# Having trouble booking an appointment on Visa4uk (dates greyed out)

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens

I have submitted my application for a UK visa and have made the payment online through visa4uk.fco.gov.uk. There are no appointment dates showing in April.

I have booked my appointment but have to cancel it. I have not booked any new appointment yet.The screenshot is attached. I want to make an appointment in April. Do I have to wait for some time for this? And is there is any time limit in which we have to book an appointment after paying the fee?

[image]

Comment: What happens if you look at may or June? Maybe April is fully booked?

Comment: Trying to book April during March is pretty much a non-starter - slots get booked up pretty quickly a long time in advance.

Comment: No slots are showing in may or June also.

Comment: As i i have cancel my appointment, is there any time limit in which we have to book our appointment after paying the fee?

Comment: Appointment for March are visible only, not for next months.

Answer (score 1):

[Visa4UK Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/Home/ViewFAQ) addresses your concerns, as you can immediately book an new date, the Update Appointment option.

> If your appointment is made through Visa4UK and you have also paid online, then you can: 
>   1. Click the *View Appointment* button 
>   2. Click either the *Update Appointment* or *Cancel Appointment*.
>
> **Why is my preferred Appointment Date unavailable (greyed out)?**
>
> At some locations a restriction has been set which prevents applicants from choosing a date within a period of time immediately after the date when the applicant is attempting to book the appointment. These restriction periods may vary i.e. some applicants may find that the next day is unavailable, others may find that more than one day is unavailable. In addition to these restrictions other days and times may be unavailable for various reasons e.g. public holidays.

No mention is made of a time limit between between fee payment and appointment booking; at some centres, it can be months before slots become available. Should you have an undue delay, you may wish to contact the [UK Visas and Immigration Help Centre](https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk/y/outside-the-uk), a fee based service.